# using inheritance and objects from seperate files

Tags: typescript, oop

im trying to learn typescript, and after i was done with the basics i found in some documentation given to me in a link i decided my next goal would be to use inheritance and create objects like in c#, i will add my code and in the chrome console i am able to call GetIt.Students["any existing index"].Show(); but GetIt.Show(); does not do anything, what puzzles me is that i dont understand where ive gone wrong and have a hard time finding documentation on typescript that gives me a clue as to what i have done wrong.

Person.ts

```
class Person {
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Age: number;
    constructor(public firstname: string, public lastname: string, public age: number){
        this.FirstName = firstname;
        this.LastName = lastname;
        this.Age = age;
    }
}
```

Student.ts

```
class Student extends Person{
    Grade: string;
    Teacher: string;
    constructor(public firstname: string, public lastname: string, public age: number, public grade: string, public teacher: string){
        super(firstname,lastname,age);
        this.Grade = grade;
        this.Teacher = teacher;
    }
    Show():void{
        document.getElementById("Main").innerHTML += this.FirstName;
        document.getElementById("Main").innerHTML += this.LastName;
        document.getElementById("Main").innerHTML += this.Age;
        document.getElementById("Main").innerHTML += this.Grade;
    }
}
```

Kurs.ts

```
class Kurs {
    Students: Student[];
    Teacher: string;
    Name: string;
    Description: string;
    constructor(public name: string, public teacher: string, public description: string){
        this.Name = name;
        this.Teacher = teacher;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Students = [];
    }
    Show():void {
        for(var i = 0; i > this.Students.length; i++){
            this.Students[i].Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Main.ts

```
var GetIt = new Kurs("GetIt", "Terje", "Et programmerings kurs som hovedsaklig tar for seg Backend og database delen av systemutviklingen og erfaring ute i bedrift gjennom utplassering");

GetIt.Students.push(
                    new Student("Henrik", "Bjørhall", 27, "A", GetIt.Teacher),
                    new Student("Patrick", "Johnsen", 24, "A", GetIt.Teacher),
                    new Student("Ibrahim", " ", 0, "A", GetIt.Teacher));




GetIt.Show();
```

i am expecting the program to write the name age and grade of each student in the "Kurs" object that i constructed in the "GetIt" variable to the element in the index.html with the id Main, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

apparently i didnt notice that the less than operator was the wrong way making it a more than operator which is wrong. so now it works apparently.